# RESTful controllers and routing in laravel

Tags: php, rest, laravel

I am coming from codeigniter, and trying to wrap my head around routing. 
I am following the  http://codehappy.daylerees.com/using-controllers tutorial

If you scroll down to RESTful controllers, Dayle talks about Home_Controller extending the base_controller and adding public function get_index() and post_index(). I have copied the code, but when I go to

```
http://localhost/m1/public/account/superwelcome/Dayle/Wales
```

I get:

We took a wrong turn. Server Error: 404 (Not Found).

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong ? Should I be putting the code somewhere else? Here's my code

```
class Base_Controller extends Controller {

    /**
     * Catch-all method for requests that can't be matched.
     *
     * @param  string    $method
     * @param  array     $parameters
     * @return Response
     */
     public function __call($method, $parameters)
     {
       return Response::error('404');
     }

     public $restful = true;

     public function get_index()
     {
       //
     }
     public function post_index()
     {
       //
     }

}
```

In the routes.php file I have:

```
// application/routes.php
Route::get('superwelcome/(:any)/(:any)', 'account@welcome');
```

my account controller ( from the tutorial) is:

```
// application/controllers/account.php
class Account_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
       public function action_index()
       {
          echo "This is the profile page.";
       }
       public function action_login()
       {
          echo "This is the login form.";
       }
       public function action_logout()
       {
          echo "This is the logout action.";
       }
       public function action_welcome($name, $place)
       {

          $data = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'place' => $place
          );
          return View::make('welcome', $data);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the line in `application/controllers/account.php`

```
public function action_welcome($name, $place)
```

to

```
public function get_welcome($name, $place)
```

since the Account_Controller inherits `$restful = TRUE` from Base_Controller class, making `action_`-prefixed function name unusable.

Additionally, you must change all the function prefixes in `account.php` to `get_` for the same reason :)